# Check valve seeping around hinge nut - should I replace it?

Tags: plumbing, valve, rough-in

As a part of my hot water recirculation system, I installed [this brass swing check valve](https://www.supplyhouse.com/Bluefin-SCT075-3-4-Threaded-Swing-Check-Valve-Lead-Free#reviews-content) about a year ago on the supply side of my tankless water heater. It appears to be leaking just enough to cause corrosion around a nut on the side. One review of the valve called out removing the screw, putting thread sealant on the screw, then replacing it - I just noticed the issue and did not do this during installation.

Based on the [image search I did](https://www.bing.com/images/search?q=swing+check+valve+parts) I think the nut is for the hinge, but I'm really not sure.

[image: check valve with brass corrosion from water coming out a side nut]

The valve does slam shut rarely, particularly when my washing machine is running and quickly shuts off its hot tap.

I have two questions:

- Is the corrosion bad enough that I replace the valve? Or would cleaning it up and attempting thread sealant on the screw be a better course of action?
- Given its use case, and the fact it slams shut when the washing machine runs, is there a better valve for this application such as a spring-loaded check valve? Something else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well just clean it up with the pressure gone! Then follow the instructions. Do not waste $ that is a quality valve. Shut off the pressure to this valve, heat and pump. Then clean it up and seal as you should have done to start with.

Comment: Everyone wants to replace stuff...I was born to fix stuff.+